# What are the settings in PHP.ini file to start xdebugger?

Tags: php, xdebug

I have below settings in PHP.ini file for XDebug.

```
[XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
zend_extension_ts ="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
```

Comment: You should probably elaborate on the "not working" and "i have made changes" parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a cookie called `XDEBUG_PROFILE` to the server. You can use browser plugins to do that for you like [easy Xdebug (Firefox)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/) or [Xdebug helper (Chrome)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc).

If you want to keep the debugger active, you can add this line to your `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

https://xdebug.org/docs/remote